# Trying to update output no error but not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update attribute's value

```
$lid        = $_GET["id"];
$check_user = mysql_query("select employee.Emp_Name, leave.Leave_Type from `leave`, employee where leave.Leave_ID = $lid AND leave.Emp_ID = employee.Emp_ID ");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_user))
{
    echo "<td>: </td>";
    echo "<td>". $rows['Leave_Type']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td>: </td>";
    echo "<td>". $rows['Emp_Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

if (isset($_POST["submitbtn"]))
{
    if($rows['Leave_Type'] == 'Annual')
    {
        mysql_query("update `leave` set Status = 'Approved' where Leave_ID = $lid");        
    }
}
```

When i run it there is no error but the value of the attribute in my database has no update

Comment: offtopic: mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please do not use user input directly in SQL queries without escaping it properly. Look up `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: have you tried query in phpmyadmin? what result you get from that query?

Comment: Is the `mysql_query` being reached? What is its return value? Does `mysql_error` show anything?

Comment: You are trying to acess $rows['Leave_Type'] outside the while loop

Comment: Thanks Sbml. I had solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the variable to avoid SQL injection

```
$lid        = $_GET["id"];
$check_user = mysql_query("select employee.Emp_Name, leave.Leave_Type from `leave`, employee where leave.Leave_ID = '" . $lid . "' AND leave.Emp_ID = employee.Emp_ID ");
```

As I understand you select something if equal to ID, so probably you ID in unique and you don't need while loop, if you need sorry :)

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_user));

    echo "<td>: </td>";
    echo "<td>". $rows['Leave_Type']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td>: </td>";
    echo "<td>". $rows['Emp_Name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Now if you want to make the post probably, I hope, you have a form somewhere, then you made the update

```
if (isset($_POST["submitbtn"]))
{
    $Leave_Type = $_POST['Leave_Type'];

    if($Leave_Type == 'Annual')
    {
        mysql_query("update `leave` set Status = 'Approved' where Leave_ID = '" . $lid . "'");        
    }
}
```